# Searching command history

Tags: bash, terminal, command-history

I search the terminal command history by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> but what if:

```
This is an old command

This is an | less -S older command
```

I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> and then I type "this is an" and the old command commes up but not the older. How can I search all the "this is an" commands? Is it possible to pipe all similar commands to grep or something?

If I `set -o vi`, how do I undo it?

Comment: to undo vi-style line editing just `set -o emacs` since there only exists `emacs` and `vi` line editing mode.

Comment: In addition to other answers you can also search for a condition and view only 10 results ```history | grep <SEARCH_STRING> | head``` `head` command will give you last 10 results.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To search for a command in the history press `ctrl+r` multiple times ;-)

You can also grep through the history using:

```
 history | grep YOUR_STRING
```

Answer (score 9):

If I understand correctly and you want to search for older entries, just press ctrl+r again.

Comment: How can i toggle through them after I enter a search criteria?

Comment: @powder366 just press CTRL+R again and again, it will jump backwards trough history